# How to create an Haskell array from a function

Tags: arrays, haskell

For caching purposes, I want to create an array, which maps input values of the function to output values.  I know, that my function will be used only in this specific range, I think about something like this:

```
MyType = ... deriving (Ix)

myFunction :: MyType -> foo

myCache = createArrayFromFunction (start,end) myFunction
```

Is this possible or do I just think "not functional" and there is another solution. I need arrays, because I need O(1) access to the members and know the length from the beginning.

Comment: This is entirely functional (and I do it quite often).  In fact, you can define a `createArrayFromFunction` function so that your code will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to create a cache, then you can just use `listArray` and `map`, as long as you have a list of all your indices:

```
myCache :: Array MyType Foo
myCache = listArray (start,end) . map myFunction $ range (start,end)
```

<s>I assumed that `MyType` has an `Enum` instance here; if it doesn't, you'll need some other way to generate a list of valid inputs, which depends on your type.</s>  As Reid Barton pointed out, this is what `range` is for.

Another option, if you want to present a function to the user, would be

```
myInternalFunc :: MyType -> Foo
myInternalFunc mt = (complex calculation) (using mt)

myFuncCache :: Array MyType Foo
myFuncCache = listArray (start,end) . map myFunction $ range (start,end)

myFunction :: MyType -> Foo
myFunction = (myFuncCache !)
```

Then you wouldn't export `myInternalFunc` from your module; you probably wouldn't export `myFuncCache` either, but I could imagine needing it.  If you aren't in a module, you could put `myInternalFunc` in a `let`- or `where`-block within `myFuncCache`.  Once you do this, `myFunction mt` just does a cache lookup, and so is *O*(1).

Comment: Use `range (start, end)` (http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Ix.html#v:range), not `[start..end]`.

Comment: @Reid: Thanks!  I don't use Arrays much.

Comment: The reason is just, that I know, that my function takes only some 500 specific input values, but it takes a long time to calculate the results. Thx.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this array cache is calculated lazily?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at arrays then also consider [Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector).  Aside from fusion and powerful splicing function, an important difference worth noting is Vectors are all Int indexed.  Using this library your generation function is:

```
generate :: Int -> (Int -> a) -> Vector a
```

Comment: The problem is: I want something which isn't Int indexed.

Comment: If you have an Enum then what you are using IS `Int` indexed in a manner of speaking.  Indeed, if your type is an instance of `Ix` it shouldn't be hard to make a wrapper around Vector for your indexing needs.